# java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Too many open files)

Tags: java, tomcat, tomcat9

Not sure what could be wrong the limit is set to 4096 and I'm using Apache Tomcat/9.0.26 I think extending the limit is not an option since the problem is with tomcat-users.xml

tomcat-users.xml:

```
<GlobalNamingResources>
    <!-- Editable user database that can also be used by
         UserDatabaseRealm to authenticate users
    -->
    <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
              type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
              description="User database that can be updated and saved"
              factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
              pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
  </GlobalNamingResources>
```

```
20-Sep-2021 03:20:15.225 WARNING [Catalina-utility-1] org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.backgroundProcess Failed to close [conf/tomcat-users.xml]
    java.io.FileNotFoundException: /opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat-users.xml (Too many open files)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open0(Native Method)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.open(FileInputStream.java:195)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:138)
        at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:93)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.connect(FileURLConnection.java:90)
        at sun.net.www.protocol.file.FileURLConnection.getInputStream(FileURLConnection.java:188)
        at org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabase.backgroundProcess(MemoryUserDatabase.java:685)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm.backgroundProcess(UserDatabaseRealm.java:143)
        at org.apache.catalina.realm.CombinedRealm.backgroundProcess(CombinedRealm.java:299)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.backgroundProcess(ContainerBase.java:1137)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.processChildren(ContainerBase.java:1353)
        at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$ContainerBackgroundProcessor.run(ContainerBase.java:1335)
        at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:308)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
        at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:294)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
20-Sep-2021 03:20:16.017 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-Acceptor] org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run Socket accept failed
    java.io.IOException: Too many open files
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept0(Native Method)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:419)
        at sun.nio.ch.ServerSocketChannelImpl.accept(ServerSocketChannelImpl.java:247)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:463)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint.serverSocketAccept(NioEndpoint.java:73)
        at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.Acceptor.run(Acceptor.java:95)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

Comment: You have a file descriptor leak in your webapp. Check for sockets and files being opened but not closed. Sprinkle try-with-resources *everywhere* to make sure it happens.

Comment: Does it happen during Tomcat's startup or after some time? `tomcat-users.xml` is regularly reloaded by the server. My guess is: 1. the server reached the limit of open files (`maxConnections` default is 8192, so more than the OS limit), 2. Tomcat tried to reload `tomcat-users.xml`.

Comment: It happens after some time

Comment: It's not going to be Tomcat leaking those resources, it's going to be your code. @PiotrP.Karwasz

Comment: @user207421: Tomcat does not leak resources, but open sockets are file descriptors on UNIX. In my opinion 4096 unclosed files is less plausible than 4096 concurrent connections, although both might occur.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz So we agree. The webapp is leaking file descriptors, via sockets or files, as I said in my original comment. Nothing to do with Tomcat or `tomcat-users.xml`.

Comment: @user207421: I don't think there is any leak. Tomcat is simply is overloaded and has more than 4000 requests in its queue.

Comment: @PiotrP.Karwasz `maxConnections` doesn't refer to a queue. There is a TCP backlog queue, but it doesn't consume file descriptions. Unclear what you're claiming.

Comment: @user207421: `acceptCount` configures the TCP backlog. `maxConnections` is the number of connections for which `accept()` has been called (cf. [`Acceptor`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/1cce34a3035d01134db61265956537d508cb9647/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/Acceptor.java#L94) and [`AbstractEndpoint`](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/1cce34a3035d01134db61265956537d508cb9647/java/org/apache/tomcat/util/net/AbstractEndpoint.java#L1377)). Each connector therefore can consume `maxConnections` file descriptors.

Answer (score 1):

This is very likely to be caused by bad resource management in one or more of your webapps, or when system loads are high and the default file handles limit is too low.

On Linux and Unix OS you can do an initial investigation by checking open file handles with `lsof` and see whether there is a particular pattern to the names of the open files - this may point you at a specific web application which is not using try-with-resources properly to close file handles after use.

Here is an example - here I similate a file handling problem that I've set up with jshell, but you will need to check your Tomcat instance:

```
jshell
jshell> var outputstream = new FileOutputStream(new File("this-is-open.txt"))
outputstream ==> java.io.FileOutputStream@4d76f3f8
```

Now scan for the PID of the TOMCAT (or jshell in my case):

```
ps -ef |grep java 
# or find the correct JVM from this list:
jps
```

Run `lsof` grep for your pid above and see whether it reports unusual open file activity for the process.

```
lsof | grep 167 |more   # replace "167" by PID FOR YOUR PROCESS
```

Somewhere in the long list you will see "this-is-open.txt". NOTE that for JVM and especially TOMCAT there will be MANY valid open file handles at any given time, including for the jars of your tomcat server, shared libraries etc. You are looking the names which might remind you of names used by your own applications (eg temp output or processing filenames).

```
...
java  167  myuser  9w REG  0,14  0 66146619527007160 /mnt/c/temp/this-is-open.txt
```

When you find the issue, fix by using code standards so all resources are managed with automatically with try blocks:

```
try(var autoclosed = blah) {
    // do something with "autoclosed"
}
```